# how can i get the selected items of a checked listbox to a particular column in datagridview in c# windows application?

Tags: c#

```
    string items;
    string total;

    private void checkedListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (string index in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            for (int cnt = 0; cnt < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; cnt++)
                // total_items.(getdata.Items[index].ToString());
                total = index.ToString();     
        }
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Items", "Choosed Items");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(total);
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven`t any other variant for add rows to datagridView.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{  
   if(listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)  {         
       // Get the currently selected item in the ListBox.
       total = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
       dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] {total});
       listbox1.ClearSelected();
   }
}
```

Other variant maybe you can use bindings and filter values if it`s checked.

Comment: If you need Item use property `SelectedItem`

Comment: When i tried to debug,I'm getting: Number of copies to create must be strictly positive.
Parameter name: count

Comment: Try `datagridView1.Rows.Add(new object[]{total})`

Comment: int total;
        private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            total = Convert.ToInt32(checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString());

            if( total != -1)
            {
                //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(total);
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Items", "Choosed Items");
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[]{total});
                checkedListBox1.ClearSelected();
            }
now i am getting the index of the particular item.I want to get its name.how can i do that,pls help

Comment: When you use (datagridView1.Rows.Add(int) - it`s add **number of empty rows**. **Number must be positive**. At your case try `datagridView1.Rows.Add(new object[]{total})`

Comment: For get Name use `SelectedItem`